# Find the third vertex of a triangle in 3D space

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, 3d

I need to find the third vertex of an isosceles triangle in $3D$ space. What I know are coordinates of two other vertices and angles between sides of the triangle:

[image]

$|AB| = |AC|$. Coordinates of vertices $A$ and $B$ are known. What's more I know that this triangle is parallel to a plane given by its normal and a point that lies on it. I need to find coordinates of vertex $C$.

Comment: It seems to me, there is a whole circle of points that satisfy the condition in 3D. Even if you define a plane the triangle lies on, there still will be two possible solutions.

Comment: There is not a unique solution but a an infinite set of solutions : a circle (rotate the triangle around line AB).

Comment: I know that this triangle has to be prallel to a plane given by its normal and a point that lies on it [added also to the question]

Answer (score 1):

$$(2A-C-B)\cdot(B-C)=0$$

$${(A-B)\cdot(C-B)\over |A-B||C-B|} = \cos(a)$$

Let $C$ has coordinate $x_c,y_c,z_c$ and plug in to the above equation.